Proof of the GNS Construction
For proving the GNS Constuction for a $C^*$ algebra $A$ and a state $f:A \to \mathbb{C}$ one bulids the set
$$N_f=\{a \in A | f(a^*a)=0\}.$$
Then the proof claims that $N_f$ is a vector subspace of $A$. I don't understand this claim beucause it would mean that for any $a \in N_f$ and $b \in N_f$ $a+b \in N_f$ and so
$$f((a+b)^*(a+b)) = f(a^*a) + f(b^*b) + f(b^*a)+f(a^*b)=0.$$
Since $f(a^*a) + f(b^*b)$ equals zero one ends up with
$$f(b^*a)+f(a^*b)=0.$$
But I dont know how to prove this. If anyone can help thank you in advance.

First note that a positive linear functional (in particular a state) preserves conjugation. Indeed, write $a=h+ik$ where $h,k$ are self adjoint. Then $a^*=h-ik$. Write $h=h_+-h_-$ and $k=k_+-k_-$, a difference of positive elements. Then:
$f(a^*)=f(h_+-h_--i(k_+-k_-))=f(h_+)-f(h_-)-if(k_+)+if(k_-)=$
$=\overline{f(h_+))-f(h_-)+i(f(k_+)-f(k_-))}=\overline{f(a)}$
So now we see that $\langle a,b\rangle=f(b^*a)$ is a semi inner product on $A$. Then by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $|f(b^*a)|^2\leq f(a^*a)f(b^*b)$. The result follows.

Why do we have to write $h$ and $k$ as a difference of positive elements?

@Monterosa2 I used the fact that $f$ is positive, so for a positive $z$ we have $f(z)\geq 0$. In particular $f(h_+)$ and the other $3$ elements are real.

Isn't $f(b^*a)$ an inner product? It satisfies $f(a^*b)=\overline{f(b^*a)}$.

@Monterosa2 Well, this equality follows from the fact that $f$ preserves conjugation. I decided to write a proof, but maybe you knew this fact before. It might not be an inner product, because $f(a^*a)=0$ might not imply $a=0$. But it is a semi inner product.
